# Using a variable for column X in sum(X)

Tags: php

I have columns A and B in a table. MySQL query asks for sum(A), sum(B).

If I refer to $row_query['sum(A)'] it does fine.

If I write $var='A', and ask for $row_query['sum($var)'] it's null.

What is the proper format?

Comment: Ideally, you'd rename those columns as you select them, e.g. `SELECT SUM(A) AS myColumnName`, etc, and then you can use those nice names to refer to them.

Comment: I'm looking for a duplicate question because there's *probably* already one like this, but PHP variables don't get interpreted in single-quoted strings.  You'd use a double-quoted string or otherwise concatenate the variable manually.